# Remote-SSH: identityFile path format on Winsows machine

Tags: vscode-remote

Struggling to make Remote-SSH working in VS Code.

My local machine is Windows 10 and remote machine is Ubuntu 20.04.   I have set configuration file "config" in C:\Users\xxx.ssh folder as bellow:

Host EC2
HostName ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
User xxxx
IdentityFile D:/1WWW/KeyPairs/myKeyPair.pem

But its not working.
I am sure there is some problem in my identityFile path, but I don't know what. Any guidance please.

Comment: Add "-vvv" to your ssh command and post the output to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using '~' (home path) instead of using the full path

[image]

Comment: Using the `~/.ssh/private_key_filename` works for me on Windows 11 (OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use puttygen.exe to generate a pair of public/private key.

Anyway the private key generated is not directly usable (it has a .ppk extension) and you need to go to Convertions -> Export OpenSSH key to get your private key in RSA format that can be used in the IdentityFile

Comment: This answer resolves my error. Thank you.